# live and neutral, led driver?

Tags: electrical, led

i just bought an led driver. but it has two white wires for the mains. I was wondering which wire is live and neutral.

http://www.banggood.com/12V-DC-18W-Power-Supply-LED-Driver-Adapter-Transformer-Switch-For-LED-Strip-LED-Light-Bulb-p-984961.html

Comment: That's not really going to matter as it's almost certainly being passed through a bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter.

As AC current alternates, the only difference between the two input cables is which is connected to ground (in your switchboard and/or at the supply transformer).

The only case where they need to be differentiated is when switching - you should not switch neutral, except in very few cases where you also switch phase.